# Binary tree, IsMaxTree

Tags: c, binary-tree

Lets define a binary tree to be called "maximum tree" if and only if the data of the current node is greater than the sum of left root and right root.

Example:

[image]

Not a maximum tree:

[image]

No helper functions, only recursion.

prototype is:

```
int IsMaxTree(BitNode *root)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a simple recursion that you can solve this problem.

```
int IsMaxTree(BitNode *root) {
    int left;
    int right;
    if (root == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }
    left = IsMaxTree(root->left);
    if (left == -1) {
        return -1;
    }
    right = IsMaxTree(root->right);
    if (right == -1) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (root.val > left + right) {
        return left + right + root.val;
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's better not to encourage this kind of question by posting a complete solution to their homework.

Comment: OK, I will no more provide the solution.

Comment: It's no big deal, I just meant (for future questions) that it's better to guide them towards solving it themselves rather than posting a complete solution.

Comment: i wish its was for my homework,its a question from the internet,i slove these question for train my test ill have in 2 days..
anyway,the function doesnt work,the results are wrong sometimes

Comment: -1 is the problem. But would you please analyse the solution. As the programmer, you can not assume other people spoon-feeding you all the time.

Comment: i checked the answer of corst,and i know why its not working,this function only check if the root->key is bigger then root->left->key and root->right->key,not checking all the sum of the left root+the sum of the right root.i promise you im the last person who will ask question without trying to slove by myself.i tried to solve it almost 3 hours today and failed..anyway,i deleted the -1 and its still not working :\